# Performance difference between INNER JOIN condition and WHERE CLAUSE condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, inner-join, where-in

I have a query regarding which scenario **performs** better in the below two conditions

**`Scenario 1`**

```
INNER JOIN [BigTable] b ON a.[BigTableID] = b.[BigTableID] 
AND b.[Condition] IN ('A','B','C')
```

**`Scenario 2`**

```
 INNER JOIN [BigTable] b ON a.[BigTableID] = b.[BigTableID]
    --several joins
    WHERE B.[Condition] IN ('A','B','C')
```

Comment: Go ahead, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) I would *expect* them both to produce *identical* plans and so product no measurable difference.

Comment: The SQL Server optimizer's job is to generate the most optimal plan for the declared query. Semantically identical queries, such as In this case, should result in the same execution plan and therefore the same performance. Check the plans to verify.

Comment: @DanGuzman The reason why I got this query is because of the "Order of execution" of a query. Does this impact the performance in any manner. https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

Comment: @Prakazz - something important missing from that page is that what it's describing is the *logical* processing order for a query. SQL systems are free to re-order operations provided the results they produce are the same "as if" they executed them in that logical order. (Some, such as SQL Server, actually take this too far and can produce errors which would not be generated if the logical processing order was followed)

Comment: See E.g. [logical processing order of the select statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) in Microsoft's own documentation

Comment: @Prakazz, as Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned, don't confuse the logical order with the physical order (execution plan). The query describes the results you want, not how to execute the query.